# Java: Modifying variables without arguments

Tags: java, class, methods, scope, call

I'm just beginning to learn Java and I have been very frustrated about learning Java's scope rules.  You see I wish to create a Method without the use of arguments/parameters.

In JavaScript, I can do this with ease using functions:

```
/** Function to increase 2 vars.
/** **/
function modifyNow(){
 a++;
 b++;
} // END

var a = 5;
var b = 10;

modifyNow();
// By this part, a and b would be 6 and 11, respectively.
```

Now this is saving me a lot time and simple since whenever the function is called, var a and b, already exist.

So, is there a way to do this in Java without having arguments like how I do it in JavaScript?  Or is there another way around this?

Thank you, appreciate the help... ^^

Comment: Java doesn't have global scope like that, it is a terrible practice for writing maintainable code either way.

Comment: Javascript isn't Java and while the equivalent basically does exist (static variables in scope of the method), it's really bad coding style at least in java, so better learn the java idioms. Will result in much better code in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use what are called `member` variables, they are tied to an `instance` of your class.

```
public class MyClass
{ 

  // these are Class variables, they are tied to the Class
  // and shared by all instances of the class.
  // They are referenced like MyClass.X
  // By convention all static variables are all UPPER_CASE
  private static int X;
  private static int Y

  // these are instance variables that are tied to 
  // instances of the class
  private int a;
  private int b;

  /** this the default no arg constructor */
  public MyClass() { this.a = 5; this.b = 10; }

  /** this is a Constructor that lets you set the starting values
      for each instance */
  public MyClass(final int a, final int b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }

  public modifyNow() { this.a++; this.b++; }

  /** this is an accessor to retrieve the value of a */
  public int getA() { return this.a; }

  public int getB() { return this.b; }
 }

 final MyClass myInstanceA = new MyClass();
 myInstance.modifyNow();
 // a = 6, b = 11

 final MyClass myInstanceB = new MyClass(1, 2);
 myInstance.modifyNow();
 // a = 2, b = 3
```

Everytime you do a `new MyClass()` you will get a new independent `instance` of `MyClass` that is different from every other `instance`.

As you are learning JavaScript is not related to Java in anyway. It is a terrible travesty that they picked that name for marketing reasons.

Comment: Thank You!! ^^ Ah!! So that's how you use 'constructors'..! Ahaha, not only you answered my question but also answered another... Thank you thank you very much... ^^

Answer (score 3):

What is the problem with having `a` and `b` as **private** variables in your class, and increment them in `modifyNow`()? And by the way everything in `Java` must be in a **class**. You can't have global code mangling around...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for class fields, not for local variables.

```
class Clazz {

    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;

    public void modifyNow() {
        a++;
        b++;
    }
}

// ...

Clazz c = new Clazz();
c.modifyNow();
```

Now, after each call to `modifyNow`, the fields are updated.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are bad. Without knowing your intent, I would say you need to add the variables as members to your class. They are accessible then from any member function.

Comment: There is no such thing as global variables in Java. Global variables are not bad they have loads of uses but you need to be careful. Some languages only have global variables!

Answer (score 1):

> You see I wish to create a Method without the use of
>   arguments/parameters.

The best answer is: don't!

If you nevertheless want this, look for **public static** variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo {

  int a = 5;
  int b = 10;

  public void modifyNow(){
    a++;
    b++;
  }

}
```